# Converting diagnostic code for Autofac from V5 to V6

Tags: c#, autofac

We use Autofac lifetime scopes significantly enough in our own code that being able to trace the lifetime scopes of various objects as they activate was important enough that I wrote a custom module that would do just that (compiles and works for V5):

```
    public class LogRequestModule : Module
    {
        public int depth = 0;

        protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
                                                              IComponentRegistration registration)
        {
            registration.Preparing += this.RegistrationOnPreparing;
            registration.Activating += this.RegistrationOnActivating;
            base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
        }

        private string GetPrefix()
        {
            return new string('-', depth * 2);
        }

        private void RegistrationOnPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs preparingEventArgs)
        {
            var lifetimeScopeTag = "*Unknown*";

            if (preparingEventArgs.Context is IInstanceLookup instanceLookup)
                lifetimeScopeTag = instanceLookup.ActivationScope.Tag.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetPrefix()} {lifetimeScopeTag} {preparingEventArgs.Component.Activator.LimitType}");
            depth++;
        }

        private void RegistrationOnActivating(object sender, ActivatingEventArgs<object> activatingEventArgs)
        {
            var lifetimeScopeTag = "*Unknown*";

            if (activatingEventArgs.Context is IInstanceLookup instanceLookup)
                lifetimeScopeTag = instanceLookup.ActivationScope.Tag.ToString();

            depth--;    
            Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetPrefix()} {lifetimeScopeTag} Activating {activatingEventArgs.Component.Activator.LimitType}");
        }
    }
```

Were attempting to update to V6 and are finding that this code does not compile.

My question is simply how would this be implemented in V6?
Could the new 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource' class be used to implement the equivalent functionality?

I looked at this document but could not figure out how to access features like the 'LimitType' property nor could I figure out how to handle 'OnPreparing' vs 'OnActivating':
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats-new/upgradingfrom5to6.html?highlight=Activating#

Comment: Have the same Problem with a Extensions I wrote for Autofac

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may want to either use the new built-in diagnostic listeners added in v6 (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/debugging.html#diagnostics), or write your own (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/debugging.html#custom-tracers) if you want to capture specific information (like lifetime scope tags).

Adding a diagnostic listener to the resolve path does slow things down slightly; if you need runtime diagnostics that are faster (but less granular), you can probably follow something similar to our log4net example (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html), which should let you port your module to use the pipeline rather than events.